# instafeedjs doesn't print the screen pictures and texts

Tags: javascript, instagram-api, instafeedjs

I have been using instagram javascript sending javascript but it does not print the screen pictures and texts I code the same as the example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '2216402239',
    clientId: '577953a9c38a4be890fb6f96326d60d0',
    accessToken: '2216402239.577953a.5c12d84b7a784b5497f383a8e1daf4dc',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id=""><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: 6,
    links: false
  });
  userFeed.run();    
</script>
```

Demo site: https://www.ahmetozalp.net

Comment: Please also link to the source "example" that you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set any placeholders like `{{link}}` or `{{image}}` in the Instafeed template. It should work like this:

```
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '2216402239',
    clientId: '577953a9c38a4be890fb6f96326d60d0',
    accessToken: '2216402239.577953a.5c12d84b7a784b5497f383a8e1daf4dc',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id=""><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: 6,
    links: false
  });
  userFeed.run();
```

Comment: https://github.com/ahmetozalp/ahmetozalp.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/default.html problem resume :(

Comment: It works when I execute my JS on your page but your page does not return the placeholders to the client (browser).

Comment: It seems you use Ruby, and the brackets `{` and `}` are metacharacters of this language. You might need to prepend an escape character in front of them, it should work like this: `\{` and `\}`. Check the source output in your browser if it works.

Comment: THANK YOU BRO.. :)